# How can I remove the double space to dot mapping in VIM? Or why is it even useful?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In my VIM-VSCode setup, I'm trying to edit the behaviour of the double space tap when in insert mode to NOT add a dot. I'm not sure either why this is considered useful behaviour?

The current fixes I found are not working and I'm not sure why:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": [" ", " "],
        "after": [" ", " "],
        "commands": [":nohlsearch"]
    }
]

"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": [" ", " "],
        "after": [],
        "commands": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you actually using Vim, or just Vim-style keybindings in the editor provided by VS Code? (And I agree, I don't know why this would be considered useful in writing code.)

Comment: It's indeed for the vim plugin in VSCode this one, apologies for not indicating that more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this one: apparently it is mac specific! Resolution and issue outlined here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2108

For MacOS, go to keyboard -> disable double space to add dot.